# How to check yahoo mail inbox without using UI?

Tags: javascript, java, api, selenium

Trying API search https://www.serpwow.com/docs/search-api/results/yahoo/search-information and https://serpapi.com/yahoo-search-api,
https://www.programmableweb.com/api/yahoo-search
Also trying with API token

Comment: I think there is no way, they are not exposing any public API and that is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Yahoo email through most common email clients via their POP settings.
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/pop-access-settings-instructions-yahoo-mail-sln4724.html